# Python - comparing elements of list with 'neighbour' elements

Tags: python, arrays, list

This may be more of an 'approach' or conceptual question.

Basically, I have a python a multi-dimensional list like so:

```
my_list = [[0,1,1,1,0,1], [1,1,1,0,0,1], [1,1,0,0,0,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

What I have to do is iterate through the array and compare each element with those directly surrounding it as though the list was layed out as a matrix.

For instance,  given the first element of the first row, `my_list[0][0]`, I need to know know the value of `my_list[0][1]`, `my_list[1][0]` and `my_list[1][1]`. The value of the 'surrounding' elements will determine how the current element should be operated on. Of course for an element in the heart of the array, 8 comparisons will be necessary.

Now I know I could simply iterate through the array and compare with the indexed values, as above. I was curious as to whether there was a more efficient way which limited the amount of iteration required? Should I iterate through the array as is, or iterate and compare only values to either side and then transpose the array and run it again. This, however would ignore those values to the diagonal. And should I store results of the element lookups, so I don't keep determining the value of the same element multiple times?

I suspect this may have a fundamental approach in Computer Science, and I am eager to get feedback on the best approach using Python as opposed to looking for a specific answer to my problem.

Comment: Can you use `numpy` here? Because it's chock full of ways to do matrix-like operations in a natural matrix-like way (and often an order of magnitude faster than pure Python, to boot).

Comment: Anyway, as far as algorithmic complexity: iterating through the matrix in a single (two-level) pass, while checking the 3-8 surrounding elements at each step, is O(N*M), which is the best you can possibly do. So, what's the problem with that?

Comment: True but matrix operations can be perfectly parallelized on your GPU. That saves a lot of time!

Comment: @RouvenB.: Yes, and `numpy` also saves a lot of time… or just running your code under PyPy instead of CPython, or using a faster computer. That's why I gave my first comment first, and then answered the "fundamental approach in computer science" part with a separate comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may get faster, and possibly even simpler, code by using `numpy`, or other alternatives (see below for details). But from a theoretical point of view, in terms of algorithmic complexity, the best you can get is O(N*M), and you can do that with your design (if I understand it correctly). For example:

```
def neighbors(matrix, row, col):
    for i in row-1, row, row+1:
        if i < 0 or i == len(matrix): continue
        for j in col-1, col, col+1:
            if j < 0 or j == len(matrix[i]): continue
            if i == row and j == col: continue
            yield matrix[i][j]

matrix = [[0,1,1,1,0,1], [1,1,1,0,0,1], [1,1,0,0,0,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1]]

for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for j, cell in enumerate(cell):
        for neighbor in neighbors(matrix, i, j):
            do_stuff(cell, neighbor)
```

This has takes N * M * 8 steps (actually, a bit less than that, because many cells will have fewer than 8 neighbors). And algorithmically, there's no way you can do better than O(N * M). So, you're done.

---

(In some cases, you can make things simpler—with no significant change either way in performance—by thinking in terms of iterator transformations. For example, you can easily create a grouper over adjacent triplets from a list `a` by properly zipping `a`, `a[1:]`, and `a[2:]`, and you can extend this to adjacent 2-dimensional nonets. But I think in this case, it would just make your code more complicated that writing an explicit `neighbors` iterator and explicit `for` loops over the matrix.)

---

However, *practically*, you can get a whole lot faster, in various ways. For example:

- Using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org), you may get an order of magnitude or so faster. When you're iterating a tight loop and doing simple arithmetic, that's one of the things that Python is particularly slow at, and `numpy` can do it in C (or Fortran) instead.
- Using your favorite GPGPU library, you can explicitly vectorize your operations.
- Using [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), you can break the matrix up into pieces and perform multiple pieces in parallel on separate cores (or even separate machines).

Of course for a single 4x6 matrix, none of these are worth doing… except possibly for `numpy`, which may make your code simpler as well as faster, as long as you can express your operations naturally in matrix/broadcast terms.

In fact, even if you can't easily express things that way, just using `numpy` to *store* the matrix may make things a little simpler (and save some memory, if that matters). For example, `numpy` can let you access a single column from a matrix naturally, while in pure Python, you need to write something like `[row[col] for row in matrix]`.

---

So, how would you tackle this with `numpy`?

First, you should read over [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) and [`ufunc`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) (or, better, some higher-level tutorial, but I don't have one to recommend) before going too much further.

Anyway, it depends on what you're doing with each set of neighbors, but there are three basic ideas.

First, if you can convert your operation into simple matrix math, that's always easiest.

If not, you can create 8 "neighbor matrices" just by shifting the matrix in each direction, then perform simple operations against each neighbor. For some cases, it may be easier to start with an N+2 x N+2 matrix with suitable "empty" values (usually 0 or nan) in the outer rim. Alternatively, you can shift the matrix over and fill in empty values. Or, for some operations, you don't need an identical-sized matrix, so you can just crop the matrix to create a neighbor. It really depends on what operations you want to do.

For example, taking your input as a fixed 6x4 board for the [Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life):

```
def neighbors(matrix):
    for i in -1, 0, 1:
        for j in -1, 0, 1:
            if i == 0 and j == 0: continue
            yield np.roll(np.roll(matrix, i, 0), j, 1)

matrix = np.matrix([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                    [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
                    [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0],
                    [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
                    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
while True:
    livecount = sum(neighbors(matrix))
    matrix = (matrix & (livecount==2)) | (livecount==3)
```

(Note that this isn't the best way to solve this problem, but I think it's relatively easy to understand, and likely to illuminate whatever your actual problem is.)

Comment: +1 for numpy. I was going to mention it, after only reading the top of your answer.

Comment: @forivall: Maybe I should reorganize the answer. Let me try. And thanks for the comment.

Comment: The organization of your answer is fine, I'm just agreeing with you.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I expected numpy would be a good fit, but I wanted to leave it open. As far as the matrx complexity goes, I know I will have a max of 50x50. Would you consider using numpy to have significant advantages for martix of this size?

Comment: Additionally - are their specific function I should be looking at in `numpy` for this specific problem?

Comment: @DarwinTech: That's probably big enough for numpy to be 10x faster than pure Python… The real question is whether pure Python is already so fast that you don't _need_ any speedup. If you've got something that you only do once, and it takes 25us, does it matter if you can cut it down to 2.5us?

Comment: @DarwinTech: Meanwhile, for specific functions… let me update the answer.

Comment: True. The caveat here is that I actually have quite a bit of work to do in this iteration and then future iterations as the array is copied and changed. Those speed bumps may add up to a worthwhile saving by the end.

Comment: @abarnert. Thankyou for your comprehensiveness.

Comment: @DarwinTech: It would help to know what exactly "the value of the surrounding elements will determine how the current element should be operated on" in your case, but I came up with what I hope is a simple and well-known example: the rules for Game of Life, for each cell, count up the number of non-zero neighbor cells, and use that to determine how to transform the cell's value.

Comment: Yep - that is pretty close to the paradigm I'll be working under!