# compute density map D

Tags: python

You are given two integer numbers n and r, such that 1 <= r < n,

a two-dimensional array W of size n x n.

Each element of this array is either 0 or 1.

Your goal is to compute density map D for array W, using radius of r.

The output density map is also two-dimensional array,

where each value represent number of 1's in matrix W within the specified radius.

Given the following input array W of size 5 and radius 1 (n = 5, r = 1)

```
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 0
```

Output (using Python):

```
3 4 2 2 1
4 5 2 2 1
3 4 3 3 2
2 2 2 2 2
1 1 2 2 2
```

**Logic**: Input first row, first column value is 1. r value is 1. So we should check 1 right element, 1 left element, 1 top element, top left, top right, bottom , bottom left and bottom right and sum all elements.

Should not use any 3rd party library.

I did it using for loop and inner for loop and check for each element. Any better work around ?

Comment: is using `numpy` allowed ?

Comment: probably not since `numpy` is a 3rd party library

Comment: Possibly related to and helpful [Python - comparing elements of list with 'neighbour' elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529838/python-comparing-elements-of-list-with-neighbour-elements)

Comment: Can you post what you have?

Comment: numpy can not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Optimization**: For each 1 in W, update count for locations, in whose neighborhood it belongs

Although for `W` of size `nxn`, the following algorithm would still take O(n^2) steps, however if W is sparse i.e. number of 1s (say `k`) `<< nxn` then instead of `rxrxnxn` steps for approach stated in question, following would take `nxn + rxrxk` steps, which is much lower if `k << nxn`

Given `r` assigned and `W` stored as

```py
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

then following

```py
output = [[ 0 for i in range(5) ] for j in range(5) ]
for i in range(len(W)):
    for j in range(len(W[0])):
        if W[i][j] == 1:
            for off_i in range(-r,r+1):
                for off_j in range(-r,r+1):
                    if (0 <= i+off_i < len(W)) and (0 <= j+off_j < len(W[0])):
                        output[i+off_i][j+off_j] += 1
```

stores required values in `output`

for `r = 1`, `output` is as required

```py
[[3, 4, 2, 2, 1],
 [4, 5, 2, 2, 1],
 [3, 4, 3, 3, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: I was thinking about for loop and inner for loop.. wanted to check if any better options can be implemented.